# How to return a string from a GraphQL mutation wrapped on restApi?

Tags: rest, post, graphql, uuid, graphql-mutation

My restAPI POST call return a uuid string as result, like so:

```
246f97e8-cdc8-4b01-9881-19278be7e33d
```

This API is wrapped with GraphQL. The mutation I wrote for this post method works fine, I can see it gets triggered and return a 200 status.
The only problem is that I cannot return that same string as the mutation result. This is what I have:

```
mutation myMutation($input: any) {
  myMutation(input: $input) 
  @rest(type: "type", path: "apiPath", method: "POST", endpoint: "myEndpoint")
  {
    id
  }
}
```

That id return an integer and any other value I add besides `id` return `"null"`.

Any idea on how I can get that uuid through the mutation?

Comment: To clarify, the underlying API just returns a UUID, not a JSON object wrapping a UUID? If so maybe don't do that, it is highly unconventional.

Comment: Yes it return a simple UUID. We are aware is not conventional but for now we cannot change it unfortunately.

Comment: Then you can't use Rest Link and need to handroll your Apollo resolver.